# how can i show icon app in Lollipop Toolbar?

Tags: android-actionbar, icons, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, material-design

I am missing an app icon  after switching from *ICS ActionBar* to *Lollipop toolbar*. Is it possible?
Please help me. Thanks

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of application icon and a title is discouraged on API 21,according to [Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar).

Anyway if you want to use an icon, you can use the [setLogo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#setLogo(int)) method in your Toolbar.

Comment: without using toolbar , can i set logo To actionbar In lallipop ?