# android manifest action bar logo

Tags: android, android-actionbar

This is pretty simple but it's been causing me grief. I want my action bar to display the @drawable resource specified by android:logo within the manifest:

```
    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

If I remove the android:theme attribute the logo appears but the app immediately  crashes due to some illegal state exception at         `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in the main activity. If I leave the theme the action bar is blank with a background color set in the activity.

Theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/logo</item>
    <item name="android:background">#F7430C</item>
</style>
```

Activity setting background:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ActionBar bar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

All I need is an action bar with the logo and a background color #F7430C.

Comment: checked it, didn't work

Comment: Doesn't it change bg color?

Comment: yes but the icon was not showing

Comment: are you sure you're writing `getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);` in the `onCreate()` method? and what's the `minSdkVersion` of your app?

Comment: Are you using appcompat 21?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768109/how-can-i-show-icon-app-in-lollipop-toolbar/27770006#27770006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know, if it works.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FooBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/FooBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="FooBar"
        parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/logo</item>
        <item name="icon">@drawable/logo</item>
        <item name="android:background">#F7430C</item>
        <item name="background">#F7430C</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

**EDIT**

Above solution will only work, if you have `actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()` set to true in your activity.

Comment: with this implemented and the setbackground in the activity commented out I get a white, blank action bar

Comment: I just noticed that the parent of FooBar style was wrong. I have updated my answer, now try it and let me know, if you still having the same issue.

Comment: Also, your AppTheme parent could have been an issue as well. I have updated both the parents. By looks of it, it should work now.

Comment: I just updated the three code blocks, the issue persists. I have a black bar, white font letters and no drawable resource displayed. I can set the background color only with         bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#F7430C")));  in the activity

Comment: I updated my answer, try that first and if it doesn't work, read through this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642378/appcompat-21-logo-as-back-button. This might be helpful for you.

Comment: That post helped, I was missing actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FooBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/FooBar</item>
</style>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="FooBar"
    parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/logo</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/logo</item>
    <item name="android:background">#F7430C</item>
    <item name="background">#F7430C</item>

</style>
```

After inflating the bar in the activity I had to set:

```
bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```